Record some tcolorbox in order to print at the end of each chapter
At the end of each chapter I'd like to redisplay all the boxes called meth with tcblower part, and in the chapter itself hide tcblower part.
How can I do this? I've seen that there's a record option in the tcolorbox package but I can't seem to use it.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{meth}{Méthode}{% Méthode
    enhanced,breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    sharp corners
    }
    {meth}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Premier}

\begin{meth}{}
First method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print. %hide the tcblower here
\end{meth}

\section*{Liste of all the methods}
% print all the methodes including the tcblower

\chapter{Second}
    
\begin{meth}{}
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print. %hide the tcblower here
\end{meth}

\section*{Liste of all the methods}
% print all the methodes including the tcblower

\end{document}


This question is similar to: Restating a theorem environment created using \newtcbtheorem. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, it's not, according two things : one the one hand this question doesn't answer how I can print the belowpart of tcolorbox when theorem is restated, and on the other hand a label seems to be needed when I want to restate a theorem.

I would like to print all the methods of one chapter, without being specified a label.

You can do this with keytheorems' store-all option and print-body key for \listofkeytheorems. To hide the lowerbox, we add \tcbset{lowerbox=ignored} to the prehead hook of meth environments at the beginning, then cancel this by adding \tcbset{lowerbox=visible} before printing the theorems. Note we can't add lowerbox=ignored in the tcolorbox keys set in \newkeytheoremstyle because they are executed after the prehead hook, so adding \tcbset{lowerbox=visible} later would not cancel the effect.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[store-all]{keytheorems}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcbmethod}
  {
    tcolorbox =
      {
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners,
      },
    noteseparator={ -- },
    notebraces={}{},
    notefont=\bfseries,
    headpunct={},
    bodyfont=\normalfont
  }
\newkeytheorem{meth}[name=Méthode,style=tcbmethod]
\addtotheoremhook[meth]{prehead}{\tcbset{lowerbox=ignored}}

\begin{document}

\section{Premier}

\begin{meth}[First Title]
First method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (1).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[Second Title]
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (2).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[Third Title]
Third method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (3).
\end{meth}


\addtotheoremhook[meth]{prehead}{\tcbset{lowerbox=visible}}
\listofkeytheorems[
  ignoreall,
  show=meth,
  title=List of all the methods,
  print-body]

\end{document}


Chapter-by-chapter lists
There is not currently a good way to print only theorems from the current chapter. This is part of the long term plans for keytheorems. For now, you can achieve the same effect manually with the seq key.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[store-all]{keytheorems}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcbmethod}
  {
    tcolorbox =
      {
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners,
      },
    noteseparator={ -- },
    notebraces={}{},
    notefont=\bfseries,
    headpunct={},
    bodyfont=\normalfont
  }
\newkeytheorem{meth}[name=Méthode,style=tcbmethod,parent=chapter]
\addtotheoremhook[meth]{prehead}{\tcbset{lowerbox=ignored}}

\AddToHook{cmd/listofkeytheorems/before}{%
  \addtotheoremhook[meth]{prehead}{\tcbset{lowerbox=visible}}%
  }
\AddToHook{cmd/listofkeytheorems/after}{%
  \addtotheoremhook[meth]{prehead}{\tcbset{lowerbox=ignored}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Première}

\begin{meth}[note=First Title,seq=première]
First method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (1).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[note=Second Title,seq=première]
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (2).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[note=Third Title,seq=première]
Third method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (3).
\end{meth}


\listofkeytheorems[
  ignoreall,
  seq=première,
  title=List of all the methods,
  title-code=\section*{#1},
  print-body]

\chapter{Deuxième}

\begin{meth}[note=First Title,seq=deuxième]
First method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (1).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[note=Second Title,seq=deuxième]
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (2).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[note=Third Title,seq=deuxième]
Third method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (3).
\end{meth}

\listofkeytheorems[
  ignoreall,
  seq=deuxième,
  title=List of all the methods,
  title-code=\section*{#1},
  print-body]

\end{document}




Thanks for this very effective solution. In book mode, the \listofkeytheorems command seems to create a new chapter, is it possible to disable this behavior?

And a second point : I'm not able to select only the methods chapter by chapter.

@jowe_19 For your first question, see the no-title key. For your second, you should really ask a new question on the site (comments aren't for extended questions)

@jowe_19 If you want a different section type instead of no section heading, use title-code=<code with #1> instead of no-title

Thanks for the no-title key. For the second question: the chapter-by-chapter display was part of the initial question, in fact.

@jowe_19 Ah sorry. Let me see if I can come up with something

@jowe_19 There's not currently a good way to do this. It is a long term plan of mine to add this functionality but it's slightly complicated. The best you can do right now is manually add the seq=<tag> key. I'll add to answer

Ok thanks, I got away with using seq=\currfilebase since each chapter is in an independent file.

I have one last problem. Some methods contain tikz material, and some figures need several compilations to be displayed correctly. However, the figures of the methods (displayed with \listofkeytheorems) are not updated after the following compilations. How to fix this?

@jowe_19 For that you might want to ask a new question. My best guess is to store the content in a box and use the box in the theorem

Please see the following new question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730135/issue-with-keytheorems-together-with-tikz-material

You can define a dedicated style, such as
\tcbset{%
  first use/.style={
    saveto=\jobname_meth-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={%
      \string\begin{meth}{}{}%
        \string\input{\jobname_meth-\thetcbcounter.tex}%
      \string\end{meth}%
    },
    lowerbox=ignored,
  }
}

to save the content to a file and record its input (inspired from the tcolorbox manual, section 8.3 Example: Exercises).
Then

Start recording with \tcbstartrecording\relax at the beginning of each chapter.
Add the key first use to each meth environment.
Stop recording, reset the counter and input the records, at the end of each chapter with

\tcbstoprecording
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}{0}
\tcbinputrecords

Example:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewTcbTheorem[number within=chapter]{meth}{Méthode}
{% Méthode
  enhanced,breakable,
  fonttitle=\bfseries, separator sign dash,
  sharp corners,
}
{meth}

\tcbset{%
  first use/.style={
    saveto=\jobname_meth-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={%
      \string\begin{meth}{}{}%
        \string\input{\jobname_meth-\thetcbcounter.tex}%
      \string\end{meth}%
    },
    lowerbox=ignored,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Premier}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

\begin{meth}[first use]{}{}
First method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (1).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[first use]{}{}
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (2).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[first use]{}{}
Third method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (3).
\end{meth}

\section*{Liste of all the methods}

\tcbstoprecording
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}{0}
\tcbinputrecords

\chapter{Second}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

\begin{meth}[first use]{}{}
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print.
\end{meth}

\section*{Liste of all the methods}

\tcbstoprecording
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}{0}
\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}


Edit: Transfer the Title to the Recorded TColorBox
To transfer the title, options and label to the recorded tcolorbox, use a TColorBox with the key theorem instead of a tcbtheorem:
\newcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}[chapter]
\newcommand{\themethcounter}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{tcb@cnt@meth}}
\NewTColorBox{meth}{ O{} m m }
  {%
    theorem={Méthode}{tcb@cnt@meth}{#2}{meth:#3},
    enhanced, breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, separator sign dash,
    sharp corners,
    first use/.style={
      saveto=\jobname_meth-\themethcounter.tex,
      record={%
        \string\begin{meth}[first use/.style={}, #1]{\unexpanded{#2}}{#3:replay}%
          \string\input{\jobname_meth-\themethcounter.tex}%
        \string\end{meth}%
      },
      lowerbox=ignored,
    },
    #1
  }

(with the fix added by matexmatics in this related question).
Example:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}[chapter]
\newcommand{\themethcounter}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{tcb@cnt@meth}}
\NewTColorBox{meth}{ O{} m m }
  {%
    theorem={Méthode}{tcb@cnt@meth}{#2}{meth:#3},
    enhanced, breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, separator sign dash,
    sharp corners,
    first use/.style={
      saveto=\jobname_meth-\themethcounter.tex,
      record={%
        \string\begin{meth}[first use/.style={}, #1]{\unexpanded{#2}}{#3:replay}%
          \string\input{\jobname_meth-\themethcounter.tex}%
        \string\end{meth}%
      },
      lowerbox=ignored,
    },
    #1
  }
  
\begin{document}

\chapter{Premier}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

\begin{meth}[first use]{First Title}{first}
First method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (1).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[first use=title]{Second Title}{second}
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (2).
\end{meth}

\begin{meth}[first use]{Third Title}{third}
Third method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (3).
\end{meth}

\section*{Liste of all the methods}

\tcbstoprecording
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}{0}
\tcbinputrecords

\chapter{Second}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

\begin{meth}[first use]{}{}
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print.
\end{meth}

\section*{Liste of all the methods}

\tcbstoprecording
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}{0}
\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}



Thnaks a lot, its working fine :) But Is it possible to redisplay the titles of the methods as well?

@jowe_19 See my edit.

Thanks, what is the role of replay ? Is it possible to avoid the third argument ? (for example by using the counter as a marker)

@jowe_19 I had ":replay" only to define a different marker when the boxes are redisplayed. Use whatever you want, like \themethcounter if you want the counter as a marker.

Thanks again. I've succeeded to adapt the code for my purpose, but there's one last problem: it doesn't seem possible to have maths in the title with delimiters\( \), rather than $ $.

@jowe_19 It isn't exactly a problem of math ($x$ works), rather a question of macro expansion, I think. I'm afraid this is beyond my skills. You should ask a new question.

@jowe_19 I added the fix given by matexmatics in your related question.
