Issue with keytheorems together with tikz material
I'm using keytheorems package for displaying some theorems (call meth below), following this related question.
Theorems containing tikz are not displayed correctly with \listofkeytheorems.
How can I fix this?
MWE
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[store-all]{keytheorems}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcbmethod}
  {
    tcolorbox =
      {
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners,
      },
    noteseparator={ -- },
    notebraces={}{},
    notefont=\bfseries,
    headpunct={},
    bodyfont=\normalfont
  }
\newkeytheorem{meth}[name=Méthode,style=tcbmethod]

\begin{document}

\begin{meth}[Changement d'indice de translation « \( l=k+1, l=k+? \)»]
\begin{itemize}
\item
\[\sum_{k=p}^n \tikzmarknode{gauche}{a_k}= \sum_{l=p+1}^{n+1} \tikzmarknode{droite}{a_{l-1}}.\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm]
    \draw[->,blue] (gauche) to [out=-45,in=-135] (droite);
    \node[below right,yshift=-1ex,blue] at (droite) {\small «On pose \( l=k+1 \)»};
    \draw[->,orange] (droite) to [out=45,in=135] (gauche);
    \node[above right,yshift=1ex,orange] at (droite) {\small «On pose \( k=l-1 \)»};
\end{tikzpicture}
\item
\[\sum_{k=p}^n \tikzmarknode{gauche}{a_k}= \sum_{l=p+N}^{n+N} \tikzmarknode{droite}{a_{l-N}}.\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm]
    \draw[->,blue] (gauche) to [out=-45,in=-135] (droite);
    \node[below right,yshift=-1ex,blue] at (droite) {\small «On pose \( l=k+N \)»};
    \draw[->,orange] (droite) to [out=45,in=135] (gauche);
    \node[above right,yshift=1ex,orange] at (droite) {\small «On pose \( k=l-N \)»};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\end{meth}

\listofkeytheorems[
  ignoreall,
  show=meth,
  print-body]

\end{document}



I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong here, but a workaround is to store the content in a box and use that when restating. This should only be necessary when using tikzmark, not for all tikzpictures.
There is a small problem that the box measures \textwidth at time of setting, not time of use. So some manual adjustment is necessary to get the horizontal positioning right inside the tcolorbox.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[store-all]{keytheorems}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcbmethod}
  {
    tcolorbox =
      {
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners,
      },
    noteseparator={ -- },
    notebraces={}{},
    notefont=\bfseries,
    headpunct={},
    bodyfont=\normalfont
  }
\newkeytheorem{meth}[name=Méthode,style=tcbmethod]

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\jowecontent}{%
\[\sum_{k=p}^n \tikzmarknode{gauche}{a_k}= \sum_{l=p+1}^{n+1} \tikzmarknode{droite}{a_{l-1}}.\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm]
    \draw[->,blue] (gauche) to [out=-45,in=-135] (droite);
    \node[below right,yshift=-1ex,blue] at (droite) {\small «On pose \( l=k+1 \)»};
    \draw[->,orange] (droite) to [out=45,in=135] (gauche);
    \node[above right,yshift=1ex,orange] at (droite) {\small «On pose \( k=l-1 \)»};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newsavebox\jowebox
\begin{lrbox}{\jowebox}
\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{\jowecontent}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{meth}[Changement d'indice de translation « \( l=k+1, l=k+? \)»]
\IfRestatingTF{\usebox\jowebox}{\jowecontent}
\end{meth}

\listofkeytheorems[
  ignoreall,
  show=meth,
  print-body]

\end{document}


